# How to locate element in selenium for href

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate the element for this:

```
<a ng-if="showLink &amp;&amp; customer.partnerType == 2 &amp;&amp; customer.isDirectCustomer" class="cp_text_link ng-binding ng-scope" ng-href="/?orgId=77bc101729ad844e39c4c1e17231c7e4&amp;orgName=Attunix" href="/?orgId=77bc101729ad844e39c4c1e17231c7e4&amp;orgName=ABC">
  ABC
</a>
```

I tried the XPath and CssSelector but its unable to locate element.
Can someone pls help me locate the element
TIA

Comment: first, check if it's not under any iframe. ( //*[text()=''TIC] ) try this

Comment: Please share relevant HTML code

Comment: Which language binding are you using? Java/Python/C#??

Answer (score 2):

Simply use text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'abc')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to come up with an exact locator without seeing the full code of the page, you're trying to automate.

From what I can see so far it makes sense to stick to `ABC` text so try the following:

1. [Partial Link Text](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-or.html)

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("ABC"));
   ```
2. Or the equivalent [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'ABC')]"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using class
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.cp_text_link"))

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate and invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following *Java* based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `partialLinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("ABC"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.cp_text_link.ng-binding.ng-scope[ng-href*='orgId'][href$='ABC']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='cp_text_link ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(@ng-href, 'orgId')][contains(@href, 'ABC')]"))).click();
  ```